# Update an object with useSelector

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I'm new to react hooks, and I'm trying to update and get an Employee by it's ID, so in redux I'm getting it but it's not showing up on the screen meaning in the component.  Here is my code

```
const EditEmployee = ({history, match}) => {
    const empById = match.params.id
    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    const employee = useSelector((state) => state.employee.employee)
    const {loading, emp} = employee

    const [full_name, setFull_name] = useState('');
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [phone_number, setPhone_number] = useState('');
    const [address, setAddress] = useState('');

    useEffect(() => {
        if (emp != null) {
            setFull_name(emp.full_name)
            setEmail(emp.email)
            setPhone_number(emp.phone_number)
            setAddress(emp.address)
        }
        dispatch(getSingleEmployee(empById))
    }, [emp, empById, dispatch])
```

Can someone please assist

Comment: can you show you redux please so we can see the state there please

Answer (score 0):

first just dispatch getEmployee action

```
useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(getSingleEmployee(empById))
   }, [dispatch, empById])
```

and then if emp data updates, then update remaining fields

```
useEffect(() => {
        if (employee!= null) {
            setFull_name(employee.full_name)
            setEmail(employee.email)
            setPhone_number(employee.phone_number)
            setAddress(employee.address)
        }
    }, [employee])
```

if this is your initial state

```
const initialState = {     
    employees: [],     
    employee: {},     
    loading: false 
}
```

then useSelector should be

```
const employee = useSelector((state) => state.employee)  // reducer name - employee
const {loading, employee} = employee
```

Also make sure you add reducer in combined reducer to fetch data using useSelector.
I think it should be good then.

Comment: well why shouldn't you use useDispatch if you go for useSelector

Comment: he has included in the code above, its indeed required to dispatch the action

Comment: Hi Madhuri, that did not work. here is my reducer  `const initialState = {
    employees: [],
    employee: {},
    loading: false
}
  export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case GET_EMPLOYEES:
            return {
                ...state,
                employees: action.payload,
                loading: false
            }
        case GET_SINGLE_EMPLOYEE:
            return {
                ...state,
                employee: action.payload,
                loading: false
            }`

Comment: ya but it's better to create the function there and useCallback

Comment: I think your initial state not matching with useSelector(), you have state.employee.employee, something wrong you are trying to get. console it

Comment: But I am getting it in the state in redux it's there. actually with your changes with 2 useEffects it's not updating it at all not even in redux. before it was

Comment: ok so now it works after I changed the useSelector to `const employee = useSelector((state) => state.employee)  // reducer name - employee
const {loading, employee} = employee`

Comment: But now I'm getting a strange warning saying:  `A component is changing a controlled input to be uncontrolled. This is likely caused by the value changing from a defined to undefined, which should not happen. Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component`

Answer (score 0):

hi you can use useDisaptch

```
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const getOneEmployee = useCallback(
        (id) => dispatch(getSingleEmployee(Id)),
        [dispatch]
      )
   useEfffect(()=>{  
     if (emp != null) {
            setFull_name(emp.full_name)
            setEmail(emp.email)
            setPhone_number(emp.phone_number)
            setAddress(emp.address)
        }
        getOneEmployee(empById
    },[emp,empById])
```